# Generate essential grid covering polygon with OGR & Python

Tags: gdal, shapefile, ogr, grids-graticules

I'm trying to come up with a method to recreate the type of grid shown below.
The grid is using a custom projection measured in meters. each cell is 256 x 256 meters.
Ideally I'd like to easily use the same method for a grid with cells of 512 x 512 meters etc.
[image: SR-ORG:7451 256 Grid]

It must be a grid with cells that are either inside or intersect with the polygon.. no cells that are completely outside of the polygon.

My thought process so far as been to get the extents of the polygon (shown above), fill the extents with the desired grid spacing (not implemented yet), then use ogr intersect functions to export the intersections to a new shapefile... but there must be a more elegant way to do this..

The code that I've started with is shown below which so far only creates a shapefile based on extents.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import sys
from osgeo import ogr
import os

OutBaseName = os.path.splitext(sys.argv[1])[0]
resolution = "test"
# Get a Layer's Extent
inDriver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
inDataSource = inDriver.Open(sys.argv[1], 0)
inLayer = inDataSource.GetLayer()
extent = inLayer.GetExtent()
print extent



# Create a Polygon from the extent tuple
ring = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLinearRing)
ring.AddPoint(extent[0],extent[2])
ring.AddPoint(extent[1], extent[2])
ring.AddPoint(extent[1], extent[3])
ring.AddPoint(extent[0], extent[3])
ring.AddPoint(extent[0],extent[2])
poly = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPolygon)
poly.AddGeometry(ring)

# Save extent to a new Shapefile
outShapefile = OutBaseName + "_LMM_Blocks_" + resolution  + "m.shp"
outDriver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")

# Remove output shapefile if it already exists
if os.path.exists(outShapefile):
    outDriver.DeleteDataSource(outShapefile)

# Create the output shapefile
outDataSource = outDriver.CreateDataSource(outShapefile)
outLayer = outDataSource.CreateLayer("states_extent", geom_type=ogr.wkbPolygon)

# Add an ID field
idField = ogr.FieldDefn("id", ogr.OFTInteger)
outLayer.CreateField(idField)

# Create the feature and set values
featureDefn = outLayer.GetLayerDefn()
feature = ogr.Feature(featureDefn)
feature.SetGeometry(poly)
feature.SetField("id", 1)
outLayer.CreateFeature(feature)
feature = None

# Save and close DataSource
inDataSource = None
outDataSource = None
```